# ExpressJS: How to render a EJS file locally

Tags: node.js, express

Excuse me for the novice question.

I want to render a EJS template in a module.
The examples I've seen render them in the main 'app' or they pass the 'app' where the app has the view engine set:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

But I want to render an EJS template in another JS file, where **app** is not available. How do I tell where to find the EJS file? What is the general way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: The view engine only has to be set once, during initial start up. It's not necessary to set it again in every module.

Comment: Thank you very much chris. I just found out that I'm getting an error because of another issue, not because the template is not found, which I thought was the issue.

Comment: Gladly. I just recently got into node.js myself, so I know it can be difficult to get your head around, especially when you come from a more "traditional" programming background like myself. (And by traditional I mean synchronous.)

Comment: Thank you chris. Yes this is my first attempt at Node. Sometimes its difficult to get my head around how some things are executing. Appreciate your help.